# Check if variable is within an associative array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this code that loops through a HTML structure and builds an array based on its data attributes. I want to execute a conditional statement within a `foreach` loop and want to check if my `count` variable is within the array. I looked at `inArray()` but I'm not sure it works with `associative arrays`?

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="dfp" data-adposition="<?php echo $dfpPos; ?>" data-dfpcode='<?php echo $dfpCode; ?>'>
</div>

<div class="dfp" data-adposition="<?php echo $dfpHalfPos; ?>"  data-dfpcode='<?php echo $dfpHalfCode; ?>'>
</div>
```

Here is the JS that builds the array.

```
var dfpObj = { "adverts" : [] }; 

$(".dfp").each(function(){  // PROCESS DFPS
    var code = $(this).data("dfpcode");
    var position = $(this).data("adposition");
    var dfp = {
        "code": code,
        "position": position
    }
    dfpObj.adverts.push(dfp);
});
```

And my IF statement.

```
if($.inArray(count, dfpObj.adverts) !== -1) {
    var dfp = $('.dfp[data-adposition=' + count + ']');
    var dfpcode = $(dfp).data("dfpcode"); 
    var dfppos = $(dfp).data("adposition");
    myfunction(dfpcode, dfppos);
}
// count is within a foreach loop so at the end of the loop is $count++
```

Comment: 1. There aren't "associative arrays" in JavaScript. There are arrays, which are indexed by numbers, and objects that take string as a key. 2. You don't even use an "associative array" (a.k.a. object) you have an object called `dfpObj` which has an plain array as the property `adverts` and you run `$.inArray` on that. 3. Even then, I'm not sure what `count` is but it doesn't seem like it would be something that's _in_ the array - `adverts` is an array of objects, so it's dong _object comparison_  - two objects are the same if they point to the same thing, not if they have the same values.

Comment: Actually looking at `count` and how you use it, I'm even more confused at what it is. Is it really just a number? Because it definitely won't be contained within an array of objects in that case. And where is that coming from? Why are you checking if the array contains it? Did you just mean to check if an _index_ with that number exists?

Comment: so what I'm doing is looping through and printing out a grid of news stories. However, our client can set what position in the grid they want an advert to appear. So, count is used as a reference and my if is `if(count is in array dfpObj) print the advert`

Comment: Well it _isn't_ in the array, because that array contains objects, not numbers. If you want to check if a particular property of the object has the value, then try what feeda posted. Although I don't know if you want to check ID, or position or both. A word of warning, though - the values you have stored are _strings_ not numbers, since getting a value of an HTML attribute always returns a string. You can convert them like so `var numberValue = Number(stringValue)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following.

```
$.grep(dfpObj.adverts, function(obj) { return obj.code == "122"; })
```

This will give you that object or else gives you empty array.